# How do I get rid of pocket for firefox?

Tags: firefox

Some of us care very deeply about privacy and security. Firefox's new tool called Pocket is not to my liking.

Pocket relies on a proprietary solution that has a different Privacy Policy than FF. The company is VC funded and the Privacy Policy states that "...all your data are belong to us and also to whomever we sell out to".

So, how do I **eliminate** Pocket as permanently as possible?

Comment: On what evidence do you announce that Pocket is Malware? I have Pocket on my Firefox toolbar but have never logged into the extension nor used it so cannot see how it can be collecting data if you put nothing into it. Have you considered using Chromium as an alternative?

Comment: How is it a malware? Give reasons.

Comment: It SPAM's you. That's enough in my book. That almost certainly means that some of your information is being shipped back to them, though.  I tried Chromium before but it turned out to be somewhat unstable. I wouldn't touch Chrome itself with a 10' pole since it says right in the license agreement that Google intends to spy on you.

Comment: I don't care if I get a million down votes, this is staying right where it is as far as I'm concerned.   Security is not something we should compromise on.  I mean if we are OK with that, why not just use Windows?

Comment: Oh, BTW. I removed it once before. There was an update. Now it's back again and all the settings restored despite having turned them all off, disabled them etc. etc. Sure seems like Malware to me.

Comment: Could you include the actual quote from the [Pocket’s Privacy Policy](https://getpocket.com/privacy) instead of your interpretation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sudo crontab -e
```

...and the following entry:

```
30 2 * * * rm -rf /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
```

So remove that file every single day at 0230 hrs.

If this causes firefox to malfunction in any way, export everything and switch browsers permanently.

Something else you could try is using the `touch` command to touch that file name and then eliminate all permissions to it. That way it will be really hard to re-create although the system may still be able to do so. We used a similar technique to eliminate IE from Microsoft back when they were trying to force us to use that.

Comment: Why remove it daily? It should not be recreated unless the user upgrades the firefox package. Also firefox is open source, so you're free to build your own version without it. Debian built Iceweasel because the license terms of the artwork were not acceptable. Isn't that a better approach if this is a **huge** moral problem to you?

Comment: Daily is a simple solution useful for the public at large. I could just incorporate it into my update script and/or an alias but that would make the solution much more complicated. This solution contains enough information for anyone who knows scripting to handle it any way they want to. It's not a moral problem. It's a security problem. Many of us use Linux in the first place because of the high level of security that it is possible to achieve. The same goes for FF, but you are correct. If they are going to be crooked, it might be time for a new browser.

Comment: If it's really a security issue, you'd be much better off building your own version of FF or using someone else's build which you trust. The fact that you continue to use software which is supposedly bundled with "malware" after supposedly removing said "malware" baffles me.

Comment: This answer addresses consequences, not the cause. This kind of a **workaround** would be acceptable for a non-modifiable commercial software. For open-source software, the options suggested by @vidarlo should be preferred.

Comment: @nixpower I'll say it again. You are correct. I just haven't gotten around to surveying the alternatives yet.  Perhaps a job for this weekend. ...of course this is more the "sit down and shut up" approach rather than the "demand security and privacy always, everywhere" approach.  Some of the biggest problems in this world can find their source in the Ferengi ideology that profit and monetization are more important than literally everything else. The same thinking that birthed Linux in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Do the following from within Firefox itself:

- go to the address bar
- type `about:config`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- accept the risks
- type in the search bar: `extensions.pocket.enabled`
- toggle the matching setting from `true` to `false` with a double-click

Comment: That won't REMOVE the software which is the objective here.

Comment: @user447607 You said **eliminate**, not **remove**.  Above is correct.

Comment: Well, if you want to get technical, I said "eliminate Pocket" not "eliminate Pocket's functionality".